# What are the character tables of the finite unitary groups?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

I need to know the (complex) character table of the finite unitary group $U_n(q)$. [Lusztig and Srinivasan (1977)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869377902770) provide an abstract description, but parsing it requires a stronger background in algebra.

**Question:** Where can I find a closed-form expression for the character table?

For an example of what I mean by "closed form," see Table I of [Bannai, Hao and Song (1990)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731659090029V).

**Edit:** For the record, I am interested in the general unitary group, not the projective special unitary group. These are not equal for any choice of $(n,q)$, though both are sometimes denoted by $U_n(q)$.

Comment: Changed previous answer to a comment. $PSU_n(q)$ is simple except for $PSU_2(2)=S_3$, $PSU_2(3)=A_4$, and $PSU_3(2)=3^2:Q_8$, so outside these cases it is just $U_n(q)$. The $PSU_n(q)$ groups are implemented in magma and their character tables can be generated using the CharacterTable(G); command. For example, the command for the character table of $U_3(3)$ is given below

> G:=PSU(3,3); CharacterTable(G);

Comment: [CHEVIE](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01190329) may be used to compute the generic table for fixed $n$.

Comment: @JosiahPark, why do you say that the simplicity of the abstract group $\operatorname{PSU}_n(q)$ implies its isomorphy with $\operatorname U_n(q)$?  These are defined as groups of rational points of certain algebraic groups, so it's not clear that one can conclude much from the abstract group structure, I think.  (Also, one should probably speak of $\operatorname{PU}$ rather than $\operatorname{PSU}$, exactly to avoid this kind of confusion.)

Comment: @LSpice The comment above was added before the question was edited to address the ambiguity in notation found in the literature. The notation for $U_n(q)$ in Conway's ATLAS denotes what is also called $PSU_n(q)$ (see the table of contents or page 14 for instance). This is all that was meant in the above comment (and the statement 'outside these cases' can be striked out). In any case, with the question of group now clear, the general unitary group is also implemented in magma and can be computed by G:=GU(3,3); for example when n=3 and q=3.

Comment: Since J.A. Green's 1955 character table for the finite general linear group is fairly reasonable, you might pursue *Ennola's conjecture* (now a theorem in most cases) suggesting that replacement of $q$ by $-q$ should yield chaacter vakes of twisted groups such as finite unitary groups.  This still takes some work to make explicit, so I can't offhand suggest a source; but it's the main conceptual idea besidds the work of Lusztig and Srinivasan.    Perhaps one of them coud give suggestions; though Bhama S. is now retired at U. Illinois Chicago, she is still active.