# What are the zonal spherical functions for a finite unitary group acting on a unit sphere?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Given a prime power $q$ and a dimension $d$, consider the Hermitian form $(\cdot,\cdot) \colon \mathbb{F}_{q^2}^d \times \mathbb{F}_{q^2}^d \to \mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ given by
$$
(x,y) = \sum_{i\in [d]} x_i^q y_i.
$$
By definition, the general unitary group $\operatorname{GU}(d,q)$ consists of all invertible operators on $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^d$ that preserve this form. It acts transitively on the unit sphere
$$
\Omega_{d,q} := \{ x \in \mathbb{F}_{q^2}^d : (x,x) = 1 \},
$$
and I can prove that this action is multiplicity free.
Equivalently, $( \operatorname{GU}(d,q), \operatorname{GU}(d-1,q) )$ is a Gelfand pair, where $\operatorname{GU}(d-1,q) \leq \operatorname{GU}(d,q)$ is the stabilizer of $e_1 \in \Omega_{d,q}$.

By the general theory of Gelfand pairs, there is a family of zonal spherical functions $f_i \colon \Omega_{d,q} \to \mathbb{C}$ corresponding to the action of $\operatorname{GU}(d,q)$.
More precisely, we can identify the space $L(\Omega_{d,q})$ of complex-valued functions on $\Omega_{d,q}$ with the subspace $L(\operatorname{GU}(d,q)/\operatorname{GU}(d-1,q) ) \subset L(\operatorname{GU}(d,q))$ consisting of functions that are constant on left cosets of $\operatorname{GU}(d-1,q)$.
The latter has a further subspace $L( \operatorname{GU}(d-1,q) \backslash \operatorname{GU}(d,q) / \operatorname{GU}(d-1,q) ) \subset L( \operatorname{GU}(d,q) / \operatorname{GU}(d-1,q) )$ consisting of functions that are constant on double cosets.
It is a commutative $\ast$-algebra under convolution and involution inherited from the group algebra $L(\operatorname{GU}(d,q) )$.
In the literature, this is referred to as the Hecke algebra for our Gelfand pair.
The Hecke algebra has a basis of orthogonal projections.
Those projections are the zonal spherical functions for the action of $\operatorname{GU}(d,q)$ on $\Omega_{d,q}$.

**Question:** 
What are the zonal spherical functions for the action of $GU(d,q)$ on $\Omega_{d,q}$?

**Background:**
The classical zonal spherical harmonics are zonal spherical functions for the action of the (real) orthogonal group on the (real) unit sphere.
I am asking for the analogue of zonal spherical harmonics for a finite field equipped with a nondegenerate Hermitian form.
In theory, they could be computed from the full character table of $\operatorname{GU}(d,q)$.
[I have asked for that in a separate question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326097/what-are-the-character-tables-of-the-finite-unitary-groups)